# IBM MQ testing using JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, ibm-mq

I've been assigned the task of using Apache JMeter to test the performance of a Docker IBM MQ with customized messages. Unfortunately, I'm not the admin of the MQ, neither I have much experience with MQ and JMeter.

**Should I use MQ JMeter, JSR223 Test Elements, or JMS Point-to-Point Test Elements?** My attempts in all 3 are getting nowhere.

With **MQ JMeter**, I got the below error.

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: 
    at java.base/java.lang.String.lookupCharset(String.java:819)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:1760)
    at co.signal.mqmeter.MQClientSampler.putMQMessage(MQClientSampler.java:294)
    at co.signal.mqmeter.MQClientSampler.runTest(MQClientSampler.java:268)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:197)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

While **JMS Point-to-Point** requires the JMS resources: QueueConnection Factory, JNDI Name queue, Initial Context Factory, etc. While I only got MQ manager, hostname, port, and channel information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `co.signal.mqmeter` plugin, the error means that you're sending the message in one encoding and IBMMQ expects it in another encoding. You can ask around which encoding is expected and try setting `file.encoding` system property in JMeter's *system.properties* file.

References:

- [Guide to Character Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)